# MySQL, Insert statement with values as select statements

Tags: mysql, database, select, insert

```
insert into class_pre_req(class_id, cpr_id) values(select class_id from classes where catlg_nbr = 265 and subject_id = 27, select class_id from classes where catlg_nbr = 166 and subject_id = 27);
```

I am trying into insert into this table with the values as insert statements. I assume I am just using the wrong syntax. Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VALUES` is only used when inserting literal records.  Instead, just insert a select statement consisting of two subqueries:

```
INSERT INTO class_pre_req (class_id, cpr_id)
SELECT
    (SELECT class_id FROM classes WHERE catlg_nbr = 265 AND subject_id = 27),
    (SELECT class_id FROM classes WHERE catlg_nbr = 166 AND subject_id = 27);
```

Note that in order for this to work, each subquery would have to return a single value.